# "Simplify conditional ternary expression"

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper

```
var foo = context.FOOTABLE.FirstOrDefault(); 
var bar = foo != null ? foo.SomeBool : false;
```

Resharper tells me to `Simplify conditional ternary expression`. But I feel like a null check is necessary here, since `FirstOrDefault()` can return null.

So, who's wrong, me or Resharper?

Comment: This looks fine. Your best jugement is always going to override Resharper here...

Comment: ReSharper is a great tool, but it doesn't mean you have to do everything it says you should do. :-) BTW, it would be great if you put your code and the code ReSharper suggested side by side. However, the actual answer is probably personal preference and what you think is more readable. Sometimes I like what ReSharper does, sometimes I don't (and I undo it).

Comment: umm.. what about var bar = foo != null && foo.SomeBool?

Comment: Just curious.. does ReSharper just gives you a warning, or does it  actually suggests something?

Comment: @dema80 It's just a warning (green underline)

Comment: @Johan strange, R# usually also "suggests" transformations.. but probably it's too difficult to implement a refactoring that works reliably in all cases..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, a full example:

```
class Foo
{
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = MaybeFoo();

        var bar = foo != null && foo.SomeBool;

    }

    static Foo MaybeFoo()
    {
        return new Random().Next() < 10 ? null : new Foo();
    }
}
```

Here `MaybeFoo` is a method that sometimes returns `null` and sometimes returns a `Foo`. I've used `Random` so that R# doesn't automatically work out that it's always null or not-null.

Now, as you say on this line:

```
        var bar = foo != null ? foo.SomeBool : false;
```

R# offers the inspection **Simplify conditional operator**. What does it mean by this? Well, as usual, we can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and accept the suggestion and see what it wants to replace it with, which in this case is:

```
        var bar = foo != null && foo.SomeBool;
```

Now, as to your concern:

> But I feel like a null check is necessary here, since FirstOrDefault() can return null.
>
> So, who's wrong, me or Resharper?

Well, to put it shortly, you are. There's still a null check taking place here, and **the `&&` operator is short-circuiting**, so the second operand (`foo.SomeBool`) **will only be evaluated if the first one is `true`**. So there won't be a `NullReferenceException` in the case when `foo` is `null`; the first check will fail and `bar` will be assigned `false`.

So the two lines

```
        var bar = foo != null ? foo.SomeBool : false;
```

and

```
        var bar = foo != null && foo.SomeBool;
```

are **semantically equivalent**, and R# as usual prefers the more concise version (in particular, explicit `true`s and `false`s in conditionals are often a mark of redundant code). You may not, in which case you could turn off this inspection.

Answer (score 10):

ReSharper is suggesting to change your code to:

```
var bar = foo != null && foo.SomeBool;
```

Which does exactly the same as ternary operation, but looks better. The logic of your code won't change.

Comment: Quicker, but just commented.. :) me fool